# How to Solve - Module not found: Recursion in resolving - NPM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

After command npm install I've to get Module was not found: Recursion in resolving, and error indicates for my local js file. That is in my every single react-app. I can not start them. What is going on? Thanks for help.

NPM Version: 6.14.4
Node Version: v14.1.0

Everything was working perfectly. I wanted to update node_modules by npm install because the npm update was not working. Now I can not run any react application due to this error.

Comment: is your node LTS version or not?

Comment: @AjeetShah how Can I inspect the error log? I would like to attach it.

Comment: You must be doing `npm install` on a terminal or command prompt. npm shows error directly at terminal and also in a log file. You can easily copy and paste (only relevent part) of that error. [e.g. Error on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwvgF.png)

Comment: I've done it using powershell. There is no error log. Just Module not found error.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem. A conflict between **node modules** and **package.json** was the reason. I've created a new React Application using `npx create-react-app app-name`, then installed extra packages like styled-components. Then I copied and pasted .js files from non-working folder.